# Not allow to create Database "Invalid object name 'inserted' "

Tags: sql, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, msdn

I was creating a database using GUI also using SQL Script, but I am getting this error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure alert_create_database, Line 11
>   Invalid object name 'inserted'.

Could anyone please help me with this issue?

This will be really appreciated.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Inserted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) is reserved keyword. You have to quote it:

```
[inserted]
```

Comment: Hi Lukasz, 

I did not get your point, could you please explain?

Comment: @RaviShukla inserted is name of special table used inside trigger. That is why you have to quote it.

Answer (score 0):

When you use triggers or the output clause (e.g. in an insert or update statement), you can get the rows that were inserted and the rows that were deleted during the atomic operation. These are like temporary tables and are called inserted and deleted. They are therefore reserved words - i.e. they are part of the SQL language.

In the same way that you cannot create a table or other object called select, where, datetime etc. because these are reserved words, you cannot create a column called inserted.

However, if you add parentheses around a reserved word then you can do it as the parenthesis effectively changes the name of the object you are creating. The downside is that these parentheses are always required on these objects and the use of reserved words makes the code harder to understand.

Try to think about what the object really is. i.e. it isn't just "inserted", it is an inserted**SOMETHING**, so call the object that instead.

Comment: Hi David, 

Thank You for assistance!

But My problem is I am creating database using GUI even also tried using SQL script LIke:

Create Database Test

Then I am getting above error, Here I am not doing anything with Magic tables, also I am not writing anything like that key words.

Hope you got my point!.

Thank You

Comment: Yes. I see that. Sorry but it does seem really weird. So I take it you have just right-clicked in SSM and typed the name test for a new DB and that's it. Do you have any third-party plugins installed that could be executing an erroneous script?

Is this a company db server or a local test instance. I am wondering if you are victim to a home-rolled audit system. e.g. Something that will detect when new databases are created and attempt to log this (badly).

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for assistance.